# Cropping image in PHP imagecopyresampled - squashing instead of cropping

Tags: php, jquery, image, jcrop

I am using jCrop to crop an image. This code was working in another page before, but when I implemented it for a different page it seems to be playing up.

When I run this, the code pics up the original image, squashes it down and then fits the entire image into the box I was intending on cropping to.

The values are coming back from jCrop correctly in the $_POST values.

```
$origURL=$_POST['CelebrityPicURL'];
$x = $_POST['x'];
$y = $_POST['y'];
$w = $_POST['w'];
$h = $_POST['h'];

$targ_w = $targ_h = 300;
$jpeg_quality = 90;

$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($origURL);
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);


imagejpeg($dst_r,$origURL,$jpeg_quality);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`imagecopy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php). Something like...

```
$dst_r = imagecreatetruecolor((int) $w, (int) $h);
imagecopy($dst_r, $img_r, 0, 0, (int) $x, (int) $y, (int) $w, (int) $h);
```

Of course, you'll also want to check for out of bounds conditions and handle them appropriately. Not sure why you're setting and / or using `$targ_w` and `$targ_h` if you're getting cropping data from the `$_POST` array.